# How Can I open a K2 pdf attachment in a new tab instead of download it on click?

Tags: pdf, tabs, attachment

I have some pdf attachments in a K2 category view in a Joomla site. I want to open those attachments in a new window, instead of downloading them.Is there any solution?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the category_item.php file of your k2 template and you need to point to the attachments filename, instead of letting k2/joomla handle the links. So, the only thing needs changing is the href attribute. Considering you still use the default k2 attachment folder, you can change your code from (around line 210):

```
<a title="<?php echo K2HelperUtilities::cleanHtml($attachment->titleAttribute); ?>" href="<?php echo $attachment->link; ?>">
                <?php echo $attachment->title ; ?>
            </a>
```

**to this:**

```
<a title="<?php echo K2HelperUtilities::cleanHtml($attachment->titleAttribute); ?>" href="<?php echo JRoute::_('media/k2/attachments/'.$attachment->filename); ?>" TARGET="_blank">
                <?php echo $attachment->title ; ?>
            </a>
```